# Spark 2.2 extracting date not working from unix_timestamp

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.2

In Spark 2.2 extracting date not working from unix_timestamp
Input Data:

```
+-------------------------+
|UPDATE_TS                |
+-------------------------+
|26NOV2009:03:27:01.154410|
|24DEC2012:00:47:46.805710|
|02MAY2013:00:45:33.233844|
|21NOV2014:00:33:39.350140|
|10DEC2013:00:30:30.532446|
```

I tried following approaches but output Im getting as null

Query Tired:

Spark sql

```
sqlContext.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(UPDATE_TS,'ddMMMyyyy:HH:MM:SS.ssssss'), 'yyyy') as new_date from df_vendor_tab").show()
```

DSL:

```
 df_id.withColumn('part_date', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df_id.UPDATE_TS, "ddMMMyyyy:HH:MM:SS.sss"), "yyyy"))
```

expected output:

```
2009
2012
2013
2014
2013
```

Comment: You have the incorrect format string- you're using capital M for both month and minute. Month should be `M` while minute is `m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the incorrect format string. Capital `M` is for month. Lower case `m` is for minute.

The following would work:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, to_date

df_id.withColumn(
    'part_date', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df_id.UPDATE_TS, "ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:SS.SSSSSS"), "yyyy")
).show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+---------+
#|UPDATE_TS                |part_date|
#+-------------------------+---------+
#|26NOV2009:03:27:01.154410|2009     |
#|24DEC2012:00:47:46.805710|2012     |
#|02MAY2013:00:45:33.233844|2013     |
#|21NOV2014:00:33:39.350140|2014     |
#|10DEC2013:00:30:30.532446|2013     |
#+-------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: I updated df.withColumn(
    'part_date', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df['Event Read Time'], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.SSSSSS"), "yyyy")
).show(truncate=False), since I have my timestamps in this format 2017-11-11 10:27:26 AM. My output value is null. It is probably due to the fact that  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.SSSSSS"  is incorrect.What is the correct format? I will like to get the date not just the year?

Comment: This is my format 2017-11-11 10:27:26 AM my output should be 2017-11-11.

Comment: Thanks I  fixed it . correct answer is df.withColumn(
    'part_date', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df['Event Read Time'], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
).show(truncate=False)

Answer (score 0):

Simple spark-sql is working fine with unix_timestamp and from_unixtime

```
sqlContext.sql("Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('26NOV2009:03:27:01.154410', 'ddMMMyyyy'), 'yyyy')").show
```

Output:

```
+----+
| _c0|
+----+
|2009|
+----+
```

Since you are looking for extracting year, i have not considered hour, min, secs...

Comment: Strange its working with ddMMMyyyy but not with ddMMMyyyy:HH:MM:SS.sss